# Foreach Loops in PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a team allocation table that allows me to use a dropdown to allocate team members to a team. I have two tables:

- `members` - This stores the persons information
- `map_team` - This is the team information

I'm preparing a statement for both tables to execute the foreach:

- `members` statement becomes `$Team_allocation_row`
- `map_team` statement becomes `$Team_List_Row`

Here is my code so far:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Team</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $item_type=null; ?>
    <?php if($Team_allocation->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($Team_allocation->fetchAll() as $Team_allocation_row) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo ucwords($Team_allocation_row['firstname'])." ".ucwords($Team_allocation_row['surname']); ?></td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $Team_allocation_row['memberID']; ?>">
        <select name="outcome[]">
            <?php foreach ($Team_List->fetchAll() as $Team_List_Row) { ?>
            <option <?php if($Team_allocation_row['map_team'] == $Team_List_Row['id']) { echo "selected";} ?> value="0"><?php echo $Team_List_Row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>No Users Found</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

The above code only outputs the dropdown list on the the first `$Team_allocation_row`

[image: Image of output]

Any advice would be great and apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology.

Comment: first fetch and then foreach

Comment: executing a query in a loop isn't always a good idea, try to reconsider this and maybe query with "group by" will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have consumed all the result set for `$Team_List` the first time round the outer foreach loop, therefore on the second iteration of the outer loop the `$Team_List` result set will be empty.

So instead get the `$Team_List` results and place them in an array that you can reuse multiple times.

```
<?php
    $teamlist = $Team_List->fetchAll();
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Team</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $item_type=null; ?>
    <?php if($Team_allocation->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($Team_allocation->fetchAll() as $Team_allocation_row) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo ucwords($Team_allocation_row['firstname'])." ".ucwords($Team_allocation_row['surname']); ?></td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $Team_allocation_row['memberID']; ?>">
        <select name="outcome[]">
            <?php foreach ($teamlist as $Team_List_Row) { ?>
    // ---changed here to  ^^^^^^^^^

            <option <?php if($Team_allocation_row['map_team'] == $Team_List_Row['id']) { echo "selected";} ?> value="0"><?php echo $Team_List_Row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>No Users Found</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you! I only had to add an extra <option> for if no options have been selected to make it perfect for my needs.